# Elasticsearch posting documents : FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Running Elasticsearch version 7.3.0, I posted 50 million documents in my index. when trying to post more documents to Elasticsearch i keep getting this message :

response code: 403  `cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];`

Disk watermark exceeded

I have 40 GB of free data and extended disk space but still keep getting this error

Any thoughts on what can be causing this ?

Comment: How big is your disk space and how much free space to you have now?

Comment: The disk is 400 GB so i have 10% free , it used to be below before i freed up the space

Comment: default watermark setting is 85% to 90%. you can increase this setting or free more disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have hit the [floodstage watermark at 95%](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html). Where to go from here:

1. Free disk space (you seem to have done that already).
2. Optionally change the default setting. 5% of 400GB might be a bit too aggressive for blocking write operations. You can either use percent or absolute values for this — this is just a sample and you might want to pick different values:

   ```
   PUT _cluster/settings
   {
     "transient": {
       "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "5gb",
       "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "2gb",
       "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "1gb",
       "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
     }
   }
   ```
3. You must reset the index blocking (either per affected index or on a global level with `all`):

   ```
   PUT /_all/_settings
   {
     "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
   }
   ```

BTW in 7.4 this will change: Once you go [below the high watermark, the index will unlock automatically](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/42559).